# MonoDroid: Sharing non-trivial data between Activities

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have some data that multiple Activities need to manipulate. Basically there is one read-only screen and multiple edit screens that hang off it.

At first I considered passing the data as a string parameter on the intent, but if the user presses the back button after editing a field those changes would be lost.

So what is the recomended way to share data across the different Activities? Should I just save it to a temp file before each page transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to store the object in some globally available place, such as on the Application object for your app (creating one if there isn't one already, of course). This could either be static or instance, depending on how you want it to work.

Another option is to serialize the object down to some sort of string representation (XML, JSON, etc), pass that through to the next activity, and deserialize it on the other side. This would work, but is definitely a bit heavier.

Comment: That first option sounds very risky. I am under the impression that the app can be created or destroyed at any time by the OS, so any static fields could disappear without a lot of notice.

Comment: The second option wouldn't work because of the back button. The previous page would get the data from the journal, not from the current page.

Comment: Yes your app can be destroyed, but generally not while it is in the foreground. If the device has to destroy your app to free up resources while it is the foreground app, there are probably larger problems going on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of serializing the object implements parcelable interface for the class you want to pass objects of. **Parcelable** is android specific concept and is recommended for best performance.