# Passing custom object between Android activities in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am creating an android app in VS2012 using Xamarin.Android. I am displaying a custom list in Main screen. I need to pass a custom object(with ID,String,String,String properties) from this Main activity to another when user clicks on list item.

Can anyone please help me with some example?

edit:

I have already tried solution mention in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763810/monodroid-sharing-non-trivial-data-between-activities)

but the problem is I am getting below exception:

This is how I am **extracting in second activity**

```
InsuranceReminderBO i = (InsuranceReminderBO)Intent.GetSerializableExtra("SelectedItemID");
```

**i is null**

and in **first activity setting** it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReminderDetails));

intent.PutExtra("SelectedItemID", selectedInsurance);

StartActivity(typeof(ReminderDetails));
```

where `class InsuranceReminderBO` is defined as

```
public class InsuranceReminderBO : Java.Lang.Object, Java.IO.ISerializable
```

I have also tried using `IParcelable` but in that I got error `Creator is not defined
in ICreator or Creator`

Following the implementation of Iparcelable on CustomObject

```
'public class InsuranceReminderBO : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
    {
        public InsuranceReminderBO()
        {
        }

        #region Objects and Properties
        private int id;
        private String strCompanyName;
        private String strPremiumAmount;
        private String stDueDate;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set { this.id = value; }
        }

        public String Company_Name
        {
            get { return this.strCompanyName; }
            set { this.strCompanyName = value; }
        }

        public String Premium_Amount
        {
            get { return this.strPremiumAmount; }
            set { this.strPremiumAmount = value; }
        }

        public String Due_Date
        {
            get { return this.stDueDate; }
            set { this.stDueDate = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region IParcelable implementation

        // The creator creates an instance of the specified object
        private static readonly GenericParcelableCreator<InsuranceReminderBO> _creator 
            = new GenericParcelableCreator<InsuranceReminderBO>((parcel) => new InsuranceReminderBO(parcel));

        [ExportField("CREATOR")]
        public static GenericParcelableCreator<InsuranceReminderBO> GetCreator()
        {
            return _creator;
        }

        // Create a new SelectListItem populated with the values in parcel
        private InsuranceReminderBO(Parcel parcel)
        {
            ID = parcel.ReadInt();
            Company_Name = parcel.ReadString();
            Premium_Amount = parcel.ReadString();
            Due_Date = parcel.ReadString();
        }

        public int DescribeContents()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // Save this instance's values to the parcel
        public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
        {
            dest.WriteInt(ID);
            dest.WriteString(Company_Name);
            dest.WriteString(Premium_Amount);
            dest.WriteString(Due_Date);
        }

        // Closest to the 'Java' way of implementing the creator
        /*public sealed class SelectListItemCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
        {
            public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
            {
                return new SelectListItem(source);
            }

            public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
            {
                return new SelectListItem[size];
            }
        }*/

        #endregion
    }

#region GenericParcelableCreator
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic Parcelable creator that can be used to create objects from parcels
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class GenericParcelableCreator<T> : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
        where T : Java.Lang.Object, new()
    {
        private readonly Func<Parcel, T> _createFunc;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ParcelableDemo.GenericParcelableCreator`1"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name='createFromParcelFunc'>
        /// Func that creates an instance of T, populated with the values from the parcel parameter
        /// </param>
        public GenericParcelableCreator(Func<Parcel, T> createFromParcelFunc)
        {
            _createFunc = createFromParcelFunc;
        }

        #region IParcelableCreator Implementation

        public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            return _createFunc(source);
        }

        public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
        {
            return new T[size];
        }
        #endregion
    }
#endregion'
```

I am putting object in intent as

```
InsuranceReminderBO selectedInsurance = listOfInsurance[e.Position];
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReminderDetails));
            intent.PutExtra("SelectedItem", selectedInsurance);
```

And reading in second activity as

```
InsuranceReminderBO i = (InsuranceReminderBO)Intent.GetParcelableExtra("SelectedItem");
```

but getting i as null.

Comment: If your post you IParcelable code, we can see what the issue is there too.

Comment: @SpiritMachine please see my edit above.

Comment: So have you got a working solution with JSON serialisation? If not, can you post the stack trace for the Null ref you're getting with IParcelable?

Comment: @SpiritMachine no JSON serialization did not work for me but I found answer to my own question after a lot of google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of search on Google finally i found a solution [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent).

Basically I used `StartActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 2):

To coat tail on the servicestack.text solution, you can just download the android DLL's and reference them into your solution. You can use this and add it to your solution, build it separately, as alternatives. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Text.Android

Also I use a couple of methods to convert items back and forth that may be helpful, try

```
static public string ToJSON(this object item)
{
  var myval = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(item);
  return myval;
}
static public T FromJSON<T>(string code)
{
   var item = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(code);
   return item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It struck me after a while but I had implemented IParcelable already with StartActivity(intent) and it was working.... may be in my next phase or project i will use jsonserializer... Thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

There's an article on using IParcelable in Xamarin [here](http://dan.clarke.name/2012/09/implementing-iparcelable-in-mono-for-android/).

Personally, I've always just serialised to JSON, passed a string extra and deserialised it on the other end.

If you're using [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), which I like, you can do something like this:

```
intent.PutExtra("SelectedItemId", JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(selectedInsurance));
```

And on the other end:

```
var insurance = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<InsuranceReminderBO>(Intent.GetStringExtra("SelectedItemId"))
```

No need to implement `Java.Lang.Object, Java.IO.ISerializable`

Comment: I tried the solution by dan.clark. But while deserializing I am getting null reference error. and what namespace or reference i have to add for [JsonSerializer]???

Comment: It's in ServiceStack.Text. You could also use JSON.NET - the syntax will be slightly different, but along the same lines.

Comment: I tried to download ServiceStack.Text But I got following error

Install-Package : Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Text 3.9.63'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more 
information, contact the package author.

Comment: found a [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/mz2_GrzFOag/55_zDJQInd0J) for package installation error...