# How do I pass MobileServiceClient to an activity?

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am building a mobile application using Xamarin.Android.  I am also trying to use the Azure Offline Sync.  There will be many Activities for various models to be displayed in lists.  The question I have is, what is the best method of using the MobileServiceClient?  Should I initialize it in the first activity that opens in my application and then pass it to other activities for use?  How do I pass that object to other activities?  Or is there a way to just initialize it on the first activity and then call it from other activities?  Has anyone done this and have advice on the best practice?  I have read this SO entry: [Passing custom object between Android activities in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997967/passing-custom-object-between-android-activities-in-c-sharp) and that seems to be about serializing data to pass it between activities.  I don't think I want to pass this as data, I want the full service to be available to all my activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#create-a-client-connection). It is about how to create `MobileServiceClient` in Native Android, but it also can be used in Xamarin.Android.

There is a `AzureServiceAdapter` class in the link, you can use it to operate the `MobileServiceClient` class.

About the `AzureServiceAdapter`:

- The `MobileServiceClient` class should be singleton-pattern.
- Initialize the `AzureServiceAdapter` in your main/first Activity.
- Use `AzureServiceAdapter.getInstance();` to get the `MobileServiceClient`'s instance in other Activities.